# XML building with less than symbol

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-documentation

I am builing xml using xmldoc module. I need to print < symbol. When I try to replace with < its throwing error assuming that there is unescapped '&' in the string. If I try to use &lt; its printing as <. Is there any way to print < in the xml text field?

Answer (score 0):

A less than character, `<`, may only appear in an XML file as part of markup; anywhere else, it [must be escaped](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) as `&lt`:

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) must not
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings `&amp;` and `&lt;`
>   respectively. The right angle bracket (`>`) may be represented using the
>   string `&gt;`, and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   `&gt;` or a character reference when it appears in the string `]]>`
>    in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.